# Convert from Canon T2i or T3i Using Log and Transfer

Tags: macos, final-cut-pro

I've been trying to read through this mess of a forum at

https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:26416

but I cannot figure out how to use the Log and Transfer window for the Canon T2i. Compressor works to get to Apple Pro Res 422, but it's a convoluted process.

Comment: This program is amazing, but Log and Transfer would be better: http://www.squared5.com/svideo/mpeg-streamclip-mac.html

Comment: there's a "EOS Movie Plugin-E1 for Final Cut Pro" but I cannot find it (yet).

Comment: http://thebuibrothers.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-canon-t2i-with-eos-movie-plugin-e1-final-cut-pro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions from http://thebuibrothers.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-canon-t2i-with-eos-movie-plugin-e1-final-cut-pro/. It's pretty annoying. Basically:

1. Go here: http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/slr_cameras/eos_5d_mark_ii#DownloadDetailAct
2. Select Drivers and Software -> Mac OSX. Do NOT select your actual OSX operating system, as the right link will not show
3. Download EOS MOVIE Plugin-E1 for Final Cut Pro Ver1.2
4. Edit /Library/Application Support/ProApps/MIO/RAD/Plugins/CanonE1.RADPLug/Contents/Resources/cameras.plist to add the section

   ```
   <key>T2i</key>
   <array>
           <string>Canon EOS REBEL T2i</string>
   </array>
   ```

I suspect that the `<string>` can be anything, but I don't know.

5. Open up FinalCut Pro and try log and transfer

Comment: Some of the instructions are from here: http://www.finalcutuser.com/?p=1829